# Web Accessibility (WAG2) MODIFICATIONS

Tags: accessibility, prestashop

I need to have my prestahop (1.7.8) pass web accessibility check and i went through resolving most errors except of 2 which i consider also stupid ones..

1. The control arrows of default theme's image slider has no contrast. (The control arrows are white and the wave Accessibility app is comparing them with the blank slider box no matter the image added in the slider)
2. In the product page the quantity add remove quantity arrows give the following error "A button is empty or has no value text." So far i have only succeeded n removing the quantity arrows completely by removing the code from the theme.js file.

Has anyone any idea how i can properly correct these errors without ruining the theme?

Comment: Can you post your code ? Without any code, it will be totally impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a scanner to check the accessibility of your code. In particular, the [Wave tool from WebAIM](https://wave.webaim.org/).  Note that scanning tools can only catch a small percentage of accessibility issues.  The number ranges from 20-30%, leaving 70-80% of accessibility issues untested.  You need to perform manual accessibility testing to find the remaining issues.

Also note that scanning tools aren't flawless.  They can report false positives.  So it's *possible* that your two remaining errors are not real errors.  Applying CSS and background images when testing for color contrast can be quite tricky and some scanning tools will report an error when there isn't one, or might NOT report an error when there IS one.

With those two caveats in mind, we'll need more details about your code before we can give detailed advice.

With your second error, it's sounds like you might have a '+' and '-' button for quantity.  If those buttons are images and the image doesn't have an `alt` attribute, or if they're CSS `:before` elements that don't have a pronounceable character, then WAVE will tell you the button doesn't have any text.

Answer (score 0):

i still can't figure out how to resolve the quantity arrows (up/down)..
I did edit the theme.js file to remove the arrows but now the language change is not working... so i ended up reuploading the original theme.js which now shows the same initial web accessibility error.
Do you have any suggestion as to what to edit/where?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).